# DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString returns the difference in time but result includes the current time

Tags: android, android-dateutils

```
CharSequence string = DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(getActivity(), System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,
            DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE);
```

Result is "0 min ago, 00:19" i only need the "0 min ago", how do i get rid of the curent time added to it.

Comment: Did my answer work or do you still need help?

Comment: this gives me back the time, here "00:19" that is what I want to get rid of

Comment: Oh you want to get rid of it, my bad

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by doing:

```
CharSequence string = (DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(getActivity(), System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,
        DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE)).subSequence(string.length() - 5, string.length());
```

Comment: I'm not calling the method on a fixed time but on different set of time. Sometimes the difference can be "12 min ago" which makes the string length increase. Can't I return only the difference as result without the current time added to it, or what should I do?

Comment: I have accounted for that by calling the function `string.length()` which will get the string length dynamically. Have you tried it? I also updated my answer to be one line of code.

Answer (score -1):

```
string.substring(0, string.indexOf(",")
```

that solved it

Comment: That would actually be incorrect because it gives you an extra space and returns a string.